# How to get data from two classes in JSoup?

Tags: jsoup

How do I combine the following two JSoup instructions in order to get data from the rows that have two different classes?

`oddrow` is a class that describes odd rows and `evenrow` describes even rows. This is a table with data and I need to get one odd row, one even row, one odd row, one even row, and so on.

```
Elements entradas = document.select("tr.oddrow");
Elements entradas = document.select("tr.evenrow");
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer to my question. I only separated the two elements by a comma as follows:

```
document.select("tr.oddrow, tr.evenrow")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use the CSS selector below too:

```
document.select("tr[class~=(odd|even)row]");
```

[DEMO](http://try.jsoup.org/%7EEJk29aFRJRNddcRvO4Dv4zU1SwI)

---

```
<table> 
    <tbody>
        <tr class="oddrow"> 
            <td>&nbsp;</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr class="evenrow"> 
            <td>&nbsp;</td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr class="oddrow price"> 
            <td>&nbsp;</td> 
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Results

```
<tr class="oddrow">
<tr class="evenrow">
<tr class="oddrow price">
```